# Convert Nat from type family call into Integer

Tags: haskell

```
import Data.Singletons
import Data.Singletons.TypeLits

type family N t :: Nat where
  N Int = 42
  N String = 9

foo :: (n ~ N t) => t -> Integer
foo _ = fromSing (sing :: Sing n)
```

fails with

```
• Could not deduce: DemoteRep * ~ Integer
  from the context: n ~ N t
    bound by the type signature for:
               foo :: n ~ N t => t -> Integer
    at mini.hs:16:1-32
• In the expression: fromSing (sing :: Sing n)
  In an equation for ‘foo’: foo _ = fromSing (sing :: Sing n)
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues with your code. First, `(sing :: Sing n)` does not have `n` in scope. You need explicit `forall` to bring it to scope.

Second, if you want `SingI`, you need to say so. GHC does not know and never checks that `N t` is `SingI` for all `t`, which is not actually true, by the way: `N Bool` has kind `Nat` but there is no `SingI (N Bool)`.

Hence, the solution:

```
foo :: forall t. SingI (N t) => t -> Integer
foo _ = fromSing (sing :: Sing (N t))
```

Or with type applications:

```
foo :: forall t. SingI (N t) => t -> Integer
foo _ = fromSing (sing @_ @(N t))
```

Comment: Thanks, András. It makes sense now. What I don't understand is the error message.  Shouldn't ghc complain that n is unbound in Sing n?

Comment: @BrunoMartinez GHC considers unbound type variables as new variables in the context, and lets you refer to them in later type annotations. So, it considers the `n` is `Sing n` a new variable unrelated to the `n` in the signature for `foo`.